# pandas converts column(Series) to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
In [6]: df.a.as_matrix()
Out[6]: array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4])], dtype=object)

In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3, 4]]})

In [8]: l = df.a.as_matrix()

In [9]: type(l)
Out[9]: numpy.ndarray

In [10]: l
Out[10]: array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

I already knew this function. But what troubles me is that after I convert this column to np array, I couldn't use reshape or other shape function normally. It seems the array type is not int or float, but how can I assign its type so that I could reshape this numpy array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert to nested lists and then to `array`:

```
print (df.a.tolist())
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]

arr = np.array(df.a.tolist())
print (arr)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

If want flatten 1d array:

```
a2 = np.concatenate(df.a)
print (a2)
[1 2 3 4]
```